# Using Google Sheets in Saas Application

Tags: google-sheets-api

In our SAAS application, we decided to use Google Sheets API, to generate docs and to give permission for editing documents online in Google Docs web and mobile application.

Here, do we need all of our customers have to be Google Accounts? Is there a better way to create users at the backend of our customers to connect directly from our app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're using a [service account](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing) (which isn't ideal for scaling apps), you ought to use google login, which requires a google account.